# Get rid of %C2%92 characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, unicode

I'm encountering the character %C2%92 in a bunch of MySQL records and looking to replace it with a single quote.

Something like this:

```
update 
tablename
set field = replace(field, UNHEX('92'), "'")
where field RLIKE UNHEX('92')
```

Any ideas on how to actually accomplish this?

Comment: That could be the 슒 ideogram in UTF‑16 LE and then URL-encoded. Do you have more context to help figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

What comes right before/after the C292?  Although that looks like a UTF-8 encoding, I don't recognize it.

You really should go back to where the data came from and avoid "url-encoding" the string.  (cf PHP's `urlencode()`).  If you are using PHP, then `urldecode()` will undo the mess:  Fetch the row, `field = urlencode(field);`, then `UPDATE` the row in the database.

Comment: Thanks - Unfortunately I need to do this using raw MySQL in order to fix this.

Comment: @RyanF - are there other examples?  Show us a sample of the full column with such stuff in it.